# Conditions for roots of quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

If I have a quadratic function $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, what are the conditions that should the numbers a,b and c satisfy so that the equation $f(x)=0$ has real roots $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $x_1<6<x_2<10$?

My answer is the following system:

$f(6).f(10)<0$ (so that one of the roots is between 6 and 10)

$-\frac{b}{2a}<10.$

However, there is no such answer in the answer sheet.

Comment: Of course $f(6)f(10) < 0$ taken literally is not a condition on $a, b, c$.

Answer (score 0):

The general criterion is that $\alpha$ separates the roots (their existence is presupposed) if an only if $af(x)<0$. Everything is based on this remark. If $af(\alpha)>0$ , $\alpha$ is either greater or smaller than both  roots.

Here the conditions would be $a f(6)<0$ and $a f(10)>0$ plus checking whether $10$ is greater or smaller than both roots. But since $6$ is greater than one root, and $10>6$, $10$ can only be greater, so that there's nothing to check.

Finally, the conditions would be: $a f(6)<0$, $f(6)f(10)<0$.

The last condition alone only means that one of 6=$6, 10$ separates the roots, the other no, but you don't know which one. This ambiguity can also be raised with considerin the arithmetic mean of the roots, as you propose.

Comment: Here is how obtained my conditions. For 6 to be between the root we need $af(6)<=0$. For 10 to be greater than the roots, we need $\Delta>0$, $af(10)>0$ and $\frac{-b}{2a}<10$. These four conditions should be satisfied. However $af(6)<0$ implies that $\Delta>0$. Therefore we have only three conditions. Now $af(6)<0$ and $af(10)>0$ is equivalent to $f(6)f(10)<0$ because when $a>0$ we have $f(6)<0$ and $f(10)>0$ and when $a<0$ we have $f(6)>0$ and $f(10)<0$. So $f(6).f(10)<0$ and $-\frac{b}{2a}<10$. Isn't it correct?

Comment: It's almost correct. What you don't see it that it is *not* equivalent*, because from $f(6)f(10)<0$ you cannot deduce that it's af(10) that is positive rather than $af(6)$. Of course, adding the condition on the mean makes everything work.

Answer (score 0):

The requirements are as you did one part, and this gives the other part to complete it:

1. $f(6)\cdot f(10) < 0$, and
2. $\left|6+\dfrac{b}{2a}\right|< \dfrac{|x_2-x_1|}{2} \iff 36+\dfrac{6b}{a} + \dfrac{b^2}{4a} < \dfrac{(x_1+x_2)^2 - 4x_1x_2}{4}= \dfrac{b^2}{4a^2} - \dfrac{c}{a}$

Comment: Here is how obtained my conditions. For 6 to be between the roots we need $af(6)<=0$. For 10 to be greater than the roots, we need $\Delta>0$, $af(10)>0$ and $\frac{-b}{2a}<10$. These four conditions should be satisfied. However $af(6)<0$ implies that $\Delta>0$. Therefore we have only three conditions. Now $af(6)<0$ and $af(10)>0$ is equivalent to $f(6)f(10)<0$ because when $a>0$ we have $f(6)<0$ and $f(10)>0$ and when $a<0$ we have $f(6)>0$ and $f(10)<0$. So $f(6).f(10)<0$. Isn't it correct?

Comment: I think you are right....Its been a while...But please follow my thought to see if the conditions I set ...yields the ...same answer..